# Spring @Value injection field validation between inject field

Tags: java, spring

So I have two parameters being injected by Spring `@Value` annotation. `minLength` and `maxLength`. Logically `minLength` must not be higher than `maxLength` and vice versa. This is what I have tried but failed.

The exception is thrown with maxLength being `0`, But in my `application.properties` I set it as `7` (Tested before validation)

```
private int minLength;
private int maxLength;

@Min(5)
@Value("${ com.manudcamera.webapi.uuid.minLength : 5} ")
private void setMinLength(int minLength) {
    if ( minLength > this.maxLength ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("minimum length cannot be greater than maximum length | min len: " + minLength + " max len: " + this.maxLength);
    this.minLength = minLength;
}

@Max(50)
@Value("${ com.manudcamera.webapi.uuid.maxLength : 15 }")
private void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
    if ( maxLength < this.minLength ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("maximum length cannot be greather than minimum length | min len: " + minLength + " max len: " + maxLength);
    this.maxLength = maxLength;
}
```

Comment: How do you instance the class that be injected whit the `@Value`,use `new` or inject it to other instance.

Comment: The class is being managed by Spring (Annotated with `@Component`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one complaining about 0 is your custom validation code, since maxLength value is not yet set (so is 0) by the time setMinavalue is called.

one possible approach is to use PostConstruct annotation over a custom method that does that cross validation.

another possible approach is to implement your own custom validator (to be applied at the class level) that does a crossfield validation.

Comment: I understand that but how would that validate the case where minLength is greater than maxLength?

Comment: updated answer, fully understood your issueafter writing initial one.

Comment: After you accepted the answer, you should have upvoted it as well. @XPLOT1ON

Answer (score -1):

You can add following annotation at your bean class.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
```

and see the result.